# I need to return customized validation result (response) in validation attributes in ASP.Net core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, validationattribute

I need to return customized validation result (response) invalidation attributes in ASP.Net core Web API
This is the ValidationAttribute I have created.

```
class MaxResultsAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        int maxResults = (int)value;

        if (maxResults <= 0)
        {
            return new CustomValidationResult(new ValidationResult("MaxResults should be greater than 0"));
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

I have created CustomValidationResult object inheriting ValidationResult so that I can return my own customized response:

```
public class CustomValidationResult : ValidationResult
{
    public int FaultCode { get; set; }

    public string FaultMessage { get; set; }

    public CustomValidationResult(ValidationResult validationResult) : base(validationResult)
    {
        FaultCode = 123;
        FaultMessage = validationResult.ErrorMessage;
    }
}
```

But it's not working
I need to return my own error response

Actual Response:

```
    {
      "MaxResults": [
        "MaxResults should be greater than 0"
      ] 
    }
```

The response I'm expecting:

```
    {
      "code": "55",
      "message": "The following validation errors occurred: MaxResults should be greater than 0"
    }
```

Comment: Maybe this can help : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/custom-formatters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The response I'm expecting:
>
> ```
> {
>   "code": "55",
>   "message": "The following validation errors occurred: MaxResults should be greater than 0"
> }
> ```

I have reproduced the problem using your code, using the CustomValidationResult, I could only get the Actual Response like yours. To achieve above behavior, as a workaround, I suggest you could try to use the action filter to handle the Validation failure error response. Check the following sample code:

1. Create custom ValidationError model which contains the returned fields:

   ```
    public class ValidationError
    {
        [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string Field { get; }

        [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public int Code { get; set; }

        public string Message { get; }

        public ValidationError(string field,int code, string message)
        {
            Field = field != string.Empty ? field : null;
            Code = code != 0 ? code : 55;
            Message = message;
        }
    }

    public class ValidationResultModel
    {
        public string Message { get; }

        public List<ValidationError> Errors { get; }

        public ValidationResultModel(ModelStateDictionary modelState)
        {
            Message = "Validation Failed";
            Errors = modelState.Keys
                    .SelectMany(key => modelState[key].Errors.Select(x => new ValidationError(key,0, x.ErrorMessage)))
                    .ToList();
        }
    }
   ```
2. Create custom IActionResult. By default, when display the validation error, it will return BadRequestObjectResult and the HTTP status code is 400. Here we could change the Http Status code.

   ```
    public class ValidationFailedResult : ObjectResult
    {
        public ValidationFailedResult(ModelStateDictionary modelState)
            : base(new ValidationResultModel(modelState))
        {
            StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status422UnprocessableEntity; //change the http status code to 422.
        }
    }
   ```
3. Create Custom Action Filter attribute:

   ```
    public class ValidateModelAttribute: ActionFilterAttribute
    { 
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                context.Result = new ValidationFailedResult(context.ModelState);
            }
        }
    }
   ```
4. Change the default response type to SerializableError in Startup.ConfigureServices:

   ```
        services.AddControllers().ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
        {
            options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = context =>
            {
                var result = new ValidationFailedResult(context.ModelState);

                // TODO: add `using System.Net.Mime;` to resolve MediaTypeNames
                result.ContentTypes.Add(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json);
                result.ContentTypes.Add(MediaTypeNames.Application.Xml);

                return result;
            };
        });
   ```
5. Add the custom action filter at the action method or controller.

   ```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateModel]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Student>> PostStudent(Student student)
    { 
       ...
    }
   ```
6. Create a Student model with custom attribute validation (Min18Years):

   ```
    public class Student
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please choose admission date.")]
        [Display(Name = "Admission Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)] 
        public DateTime AdmissionDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Min18Years]
        public DateTime DateofBirth { get; set; }
    }


    public class Min18Years : ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var student = (Student)validationContext.ObjectInstance;

            if (student.DateofBirth == null)
                return new ValidationResult("Date of Birth is required.");

            var age = DateTime.Today.Year - student.DateofBirth.Year;

            if (age <= 0)
            { 
                return new ValidationResult("MaxResults should be greater than 0");
            } 
            return (age >= 18)
                ? ValidationResult.Success
                : new ValidationResult("Student should be at least 18 years old.");
        }
    }
   ```

After running the application, the result like this:

[image]

Reference:

[Handle Validation failure errors in ASP.NET Core web APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#validation-failure-error-response)

[Handling validation responses for ASP.NET Core Web API](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/validation-response-aspnet-core-webapi/)