# How to modify auto [ApiController] validation response for some endpoints only?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, validation, asp.net-apicontroller

I have to modify auto validation response that `[ApiController]` generates but only for some endpoints, so I can't change `ApiBehaviorOptions`. I tried using `IActionFilter`, but the auto validation is done before action filter and I can't modify it this way.

How can I modify auto validation response for some actions only?

Comment: Custom Attribute that you'll have to handle on both the client and server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0#custom-attributes

Comment: I mentioned about API, so I dont need to handle anything on client. What's more, I'm not asking how to create custom validation attribute, but how to modify validation response auto generated by `ApiController`.

Comment: If you want the validation message to change for all Actions, you can add the `ErrorMessge` attribute to auto validation. If you want to [use the action filter to handle the Validation failure error response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64280264/18789859), you need to remove or disable auto validation response. It looks like you cannot modify the default auto-validation message for the specified Action.